# laravel how to pass the data from form to controller

Tags: html, laravel, database

I am trying to pass the data from the HTML form to the controller but when I use the dd function it's don't show me any input values from the HTML  , it's working with the another HTML page with the same controller
my controller

```php
public function carEdit(Request $request, Cars $cars, $id)
{
    $data = $request->input();

    dd($data); //when use dd it's give me 
    // array:1 [▼
    //  "_token" => "UE36YHG6TF1HnGsAkLFJAOFsrACZ8pmL3Ya9iFHE"
    //]
    // I think it should show me the input values in the form like this:
    // array:1 [▼
    // 'title'
    // 'content'
    // 'youtube'
    // ...etc]
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->where('id',$id)->get();
    $car = Cars::findOrFail($id);
    // $car->title = $data['title'];
    // $car->content = $data['content'];
    // $car->youtubevid = $data['youtubevid'];
    // $car->bannerimage = $data['bannerimage'];
    // $car->extrainfo = $data['extrainfo'];
    // $car->location = $data['location'];
    // $car->car_price = $data['car_price'];
    $car->update();

    return view('/dashboard/editCars')->with('cars',$cars);
}
```

HTML code

```xml
@extends('dashboard.base')

@section('content')
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="fade-in">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"> edit car</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="body">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">title</th>
                    <th scope="col">content</th>
                    <th scope="col">youtube</th>
                    <th scope="col">banner image</th>
                    <th scope="col">extra info</th>
                    <th scope="col">location</th>
                    <th scope="col">pricing</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {{-- {{ dd($cars) }} --}}
                  @if (count($cars) != 0)
                    @foreach ($cars as $cars)
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">#</th>
                        <th >{{ $cars->title }}</th>
                        <td>{{ $cars->content }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $cars->youtubevid }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $cars->bannerimage }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $cars->extrainfo }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $cars->location }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $cars->car_price }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                </tbody>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <form method="post" action="/cars/{id}/edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      @csrf
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="text" id="title"name="title" size="6" placeholder="new title"></input></th>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="content" size="6" placeholder="new content"></input></th>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="youtube" size="6" placeholder="new youtube"></input></th>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="bannerimage" size="6" placeholder="new banner image"></input></th>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="extrainfo" size="6" placeholder="new extra info"></input></th>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="location" size="6" placeholder="new location"></input></th>
                        <th scope="col"><input type="text" name="pricing" size="6" placeholder="new pricing"></input></th>
                      </form>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="location.href='/cars'">update</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endsection
    @section('javascript')
      <script src="{{ asset('js/colors.js') }}"></script>
    @endsection
```

Comment: You're declaring multiple forms and your table layout has 2 thead elements. Your submit button doesn't know which form to submit.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing Id as static.
I think the best way to do this you should just

```
 <form method="post" action="/cars/$variableYouWantToPassHere/edit" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" >

public function carEdit(Request $request, $id){
        $data = $request->all();

        dd($data);//when use dd it's give me 
    }
```

then in your route

```
Route::POST('/cars/{id}/edit','YOURCONTROLLER@carEdit');
```